# Does mutual singularity of measures imply absolute continuity?

Tags: measure-theory, singular-measures

I know that, a measure $\nu$ is *absolutely continuous* with respect to another measure $\mu$ if $\mu(A)=0$ implies $\nu(A)=0$. and the relation is indicated by $\nu<<\mu$.
On the other hand, measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ are *mutually singular* if they have disjoint support. that is, there exist set $S_\mu$ and $S_\nu$ such that
$$ 
S_\mu \cap S_\nu=\emptyset,\\
\mu(\Omega-S_\mu)=0,  \\
\nu(\Omega-S_\nu)=0.
$$
My question is that, do these concepts coincide (in some case)? I mean, given singularity, is it possible to get absolute continuity (or vice versa)?

Thank you

Comment: I don't know if it really answers your question but you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_decomposition_theorem

Comment: The two notions don't coincide - they're in some sense te exact opposites of each other! Look at the definitions: If $\nu$ and $\mu$ are singular then $\mu(S_\nu)=0$ while $\nu(S_\nu)=\nu(X)$. This says that $\nu$ is _not_ absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$, unless $\nu=0$.

Comment: Additional comment: In the first part of your post,  you have mixed up $\mu,\nu $ somewhat.

Comment: Thank you @Augustin it was useful.

Comment: Thank you @David , It was interesting. Is there an example where $\nu<<\mu$ and $\mu<<\nu$ but they are not mutually singular?

Comment: "But" they are not mutually singular? Read what I wrote again. More carefully.